# Greping a tcpdump with tshark

Tags: bash, grep, pipeline, tcpdump

I'm trying to program a little "dirty" website filter - e.g. an user wants to visit an erotic website (based on domain name)

So basically, I got something like

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo tshark -i any tcp port 80 or tcp port 443 -V | grep "Host.*keyword"
```

It works great but now I need to do some actions after I find something (iptables and DROPing packets...). The problem I got is that tcp dumping is still running. If I had a complete file with data, the thing I'm trying to reach is easy to solve.

In pseudocoude, I'd like to have something like:

```
if (tshark and grep found something)
    iptables - drop packets 
    sleep 600 # a punishment for an user
    iptables accept packets I was dropping
else 
    still look for a match in the tcp dump that's still running
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like the following:

```
tshark OPTIONS 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered PATTERN | while read line; do
    # actions for when the pattern is found, the matched input is in $line
    break
done
```

The `2>&1` is important so that when PATTERN is matched and the while loop terminates, `tshark` has nowhere to write to and terminates because of the broken pipe.

If you want to keep `tshark` running and analyze future output, just remove the `break`. This way, the while loop never terminates and it keeps reading the filtered output from `tshark`.

Comment: +1, although you may want to [specify line-buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5503084/753731) to grep to avoid starvation in the read loop